# SSAS -> Cube Deployment -> Unable to deploy cube without processing each dimension individually?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, cube

I have noticed that when creating my cubes if I create my cube via the cube wizard and then instantly go and attempt to deploy my cube I encounter a bunch of odd errors regarding attribute keys not being present (basically referential integrity issues)  If I go through and individually process each of my 15+ dimensions (no errors occur), and then deploy my cube it works without error.  I am just wondering if anyone else has experienced this or if this is just something due to the order in which the dimensions are being processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using referenced dimensions? Are you processing the cube in one job, full process, single transaction? Do you have RI errors in the underlying data?

Comment: Not using referenced dimensions.  I do not truly have RI errors in the underlying data.  I am encountering the error during the deployment stage of my cube when I have not processed my dimensions and it tries to process my dimensions prior to deployment.  Processing option is default, Transactional Deployment is false.

Comment: @UserSmith If I remember rightly, a deployment is deploy then process. So it puts the changes onto the target, then processes. Have you done anything odd with dimension members like declaring attribute relationships that don't exist? Have you tried (If possible) deleting the existing cube on the server, then deploying from VS?

Comment: No, to the relationships, first thing that I reviewed.  I have not tried deleting on the server.  I would rather just recreate the cube in its entirety which I have done several times, but each time I recreate the cube in its entirety I still have to process all the dimensions prior to deployment.  They process fine, but if I just deploy first I get all kinds of errors.  If I process the dimensions first then deploy it works perfectly.  Maybe that is the way it needs to be done, but I understood that this was not the way that it needed to be done?